# Enterprise Library FileConfigurationSource looking in the path of the calling app

Tags: enterprise-library

"The configuration file C:\mywebapp\mydoamin.dll.config could not be found."

mywebapp domain is the originating code. mydomain is the executing code that references FileConfigurationSource and that is where the config file is located. I'm expecting it to look in mydomain... c:\mydomain\mydomain.dll.config instead. Am I missing something?

Comment: More details please. What does the code/config look like that sets up the config source?

Comment: mydomain.FileConfiguration() in executing code
FileConfigurationSource file = new FileConfigurationSource("mydomain.dll.config");

webpage calling code simply calls this class method. The config file is not setup in the web code but in the assembly mydomain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a relative path with `FileConfigurationSource` it is going to look for the file in the `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` directory.  Actually, it will combine the BaseDirectory with the relative path given as the constructor argument to try to locate the file.

You either need to deploy the configuration file into the web root directory (based on your current code) or use an absolute path.